# Interfaces for Page Objects in Geb and Spock

Tags: selenium, groovy, geb

When I was using Java + selenium I was used to create interfaces for Page Objects and then I use for example Spring to bind specific implementation to abstract interface. 
My files could look like this: 
src\main\pageobjects\MyPageInterface 
src\main\pageobjects\MyPageWebImpl 
src\main\pageobjects\MyPageMobileImpl 
src\test\Test 
So I was able to wite one test and run it against two different implementations (in this case one for desktop and one for mobile).

How I can do this in Geb using Geb page object http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/#pages?

Comment: I would look at Spock's data driven tests.  You should be be able to essentially run the same spec against different implementations with that.

Comment: http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.0/data_driven_testing.html

Comment: You are right, I did not think this way but it works for me. Thanks!

Comment: Cool.  I'll 'answer' if you wanna give me props.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spock's data driven tests should be be able to run the same spec against different implementations.

http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.0/data_driven_testing.html